# IExplorerBrowser control in python

Tags: python, com, win32com

I'm try to embed a IExplorerBrowser (Windows Explorer) in a wxpython application but I cannot seem to get the IExplorerBrowser module opened in python

I have the CLSID of IExplorerBrowser from the registry but when I try and open it with:

```
from win32com import client

client.gencache.GetModuleForCLSID(id)
```

Nothing is returned.. i.e. the module does not exist.

Am I going about this the wrong way? I usually use makepy to generate COM wrappers and open them with client.Dispatch, getting the object names from the makepy generated code. However, I can not find the IExplorerBrowser object in the makepy COM browser and am pretty much stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the windows [shell interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774328(v=VS.85).aspx) can be accessed from [win32com.shell](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32com.shell_and_Windows_Shell_Links.html).  Also take a look at the sample `explorer_browser.py`, which should be in your `site-packages/win32comext/shell/demos` directory.

Comment: Ahh thank you! The demo works but unfortunately I cannot seem to embed the ExplorerBrowser in a wx window. I cannot use MakeActiveXClass on the PyExplorerBrowser object returned from CoCreateInstance. I am looking into ways to embed the win32gui stuff into a wx window.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, not sure how to embed since I've never tried that.  Maybe you can try asking on the wxPython users list: http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users/topics